# Grid Fill Loops are not connected by wire/boundary edges

Tags: modeling, vertices

Want to grid fill selection (circle in picture) but get "**Loops are not connected by wire/boundary edges**" error. Am exhausted for solutions. There are no double vertices, the circle selects flawlessly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> (so it is one continuous loop), there are an even number (32) of vertices in the circle.

[image: circle to grid fill]

Answer (score 7):

If it was possible to *Grid Fill* the selected edges, you would get edges that are shared by 3 faces.

[image]

It is technically *allowed* topology, but is not considered *correct* topology. Most tools don't produce this awkward topology because it is rarely desirable due to how normals and subsurf are calculated.

[image]

In the image above I duplicated the *edge ring* so it isn't joined to the original *edge ring*, then did a *Grid Fill*. If you really wanted to make a problem mesh you could remove doubles and it would merge the edges. But you will not be able to force the *Grid Fill* to produce mesh results that are considered bad.

Answer (score 6):

Adding a tiny bit to @zeffii's answer (who described the essence of the problem - edges shared by more than 2 faces, that will become non-manifold);
here's another example on which topology the grid fill will and will not allow, resembling your case:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Zeffi's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43988/5705) and [TLousky's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43989/5705) answers adequately cover the topological reasons creating a face in that spot should be avoided.  But I thought I would explain how I would create a topologically-sound face in that spot.

First bevel the edge loop where you want to create the face with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, then delete the resulting new face loop and grid fill the two boundary edge loops separately.

[image]

This process fills the top as you want, but keeps the geometry "nice" and manifold with good topology.